# grep ifconfig output using shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose this is the o/p of my ifconfig command
I want to extract HWaddr value i.e 52:54:00:1f:fd:a4 value of ens3. How do I do it In shell script i am running ifconfig command and then trying to grep.. how do i gre

```
 ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:1f:fd:a4
              inet addr:10.54.81.88  Bcast:10.54.81.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fd00:10:6b50:4510::5b/64 Scope:Global
              inet6 addr: fd00:10:6b50:4510::5a/64 Scope:Global
              inet6 addr: fd00:10:6b50:4510::59/64 Scope:Global
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below. How will it work? `ifconfig -a` will redirect above mac address information to `grep` and `grep` will find out the line containing word `HWaddr` and will redirect the out put to `awk` command and finally `awk` cut and print the 5th column from that line.

```
 ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr |awk '{print $5}'
```

after the above command your output will be:-

```
52:54:00:1f:fd:a4
```

Now a proper shell script for this:-

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# Above line instruct in which shell you want this script to run. 
MAC_ADD=$(ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr |awk '{print $5}')
echo $MAC_ADD
```

Comment: this will give me HWaddr of all the interfaces

Comment: either use `ifconfig -a | grep Ethernet |awk '{print $5}'` or `ifconfig -a | grep ens3 |awk '{print $5}'`

Comment: Yes its working , Thanks Abhhijit